# finding the range of the linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $T: P\to P $ defined by $T(p)(x)=p^"(x)-2p(x)$ then how shall I find the range of $T$ . The answer is given but I don't know the process to finding out . So please explain.

Comment: What is the set $P$?

Answer (score 0):

$T=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+2\operatorname{id}$, the ranges of the both maps and their sum are subspaces of $P$, in particulular the range of the latter is the whole $P$. Hence, $\operatorname{range}(T)=P$.